# Stanford CS106A : Eclipse highlighted my method declaration and code can't compile

Tags: java, eclipse, serialization

Here is the code. Eclipse highlighted the `FindRange` method. The hint to the error reads

> The serializable class `FindRange` does not declare a `static final serialVersionUID` field of type `long`.

Any help?

Here is the code:

```
/*
 * File: FindRange.java
 * Name: 
 * Section Leader: 
 * --------------------
 * This file is the starter file for the FindRange problem.
 */

import acm.program.*;

public class FindRange extends ConsoleProgram {
    public void run() {
        /* You fill this in */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ConsoleProgram` class that your class is extending must be declared as `implements Serializable`; in consequence, your `FindRange` class is also `Serializable`. The purpose of a `Serializable` class is to allow an instance to be turned into a stream of bytes that can be sent over a network or saved to disk or similar, and then reinterpreted later to have the instance constructed.

A `Serializable` class is supposed to declare a

```
public static final long serialVersionUID = ...;
```

which should change every time you make a non-trivial change to the class, in order to ensure that old instances that got saved somewhere won't deserialize in a problematic way.

If this is homework, then ignore it for this class. If your professor is using serialization on your answers for some reason, then it'll work fine without the versioning, because he'll only be running it once, through some kind of test harness that throws the instances away afterwards. (And if he really needed you to declare a version number, he'd have told you.) IF you want to add the field it's complaining about, then do so: it also won't do any harm.

**But** you say that Eclipse is refusing to compile the file. That ought not to be the case: it should give a warning, but not refuse to compile it. (I suppose it's possible that you've changed the Eclipse settings to turn this into an error rather than a warning, but that seems extremely unlikely.)

Comment: Thanks. It compiles after changing the settings on warnings in my Eclipse.

Comment: @VladimirFomene You're welcome. Please do click the tick to mark as accepted answer if you found it useful.